# React-native run from IDE vs command line

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react-native app. I'm running it in the Android emulator, on OSX.

When I run from Android Studio by pressing the "play" button it works.

When I start the metro bundler ("react-native start" in the root directory) I get:

```
undefined is not an object 
(evaluating 'react2.PropTypes.number')
```

I understand what this error is (an old version of a library).

What I don't understand is why it is working via Android Studio.

It's 100% reproducible using these steps:

1. Run in Android Studio. Works correctly.
2. Stop via Android Studio.
3. react-native start and run in Android Studio (or just react-native run-android)
4. Fails to load (with error above)
5. Stop metro bundler
6. Clean Android Studio project
7. Rebuild and run in Android Studio (works correctly)

Obviously the bundling of libraries is working differently, but I don't know where to look for what the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

Could be possible your Android Studio installing the app in Release mode?

Comment: I don't think so. In Build -> Build Variants they are all set to debug.

Comment: But OTOH, running via the command line (if I bypass the error above) I do get deprecated "isMounted" warnings, and I don't get them if I run via Android Studio. My understanding is that release build hide these. So.. maybe? I don't know!??